# How prove this $\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k}\right)^2=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

let sequence $\{a_{k}\},k=0,1,2,\cdots,n,\cdots$ such 
$$a_{0}a_{k}+a_{1}a_{k-1}+\cdots+a_{k}a_{0}=0,\forall k\in N^{+}$$

show that $$\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k}\right)^2=0$$

since
$k=0$,then we have $a^2_{0}=0$

$k=1$,then we have
$$a_{0}a_{1}+a_{1}a_{0}=0\Longrightarrow 2a_{1}a_{0}=0\Longrightarrow (a_{0}+a_{1})^2=0$$

I fell we can use  mathematical induction to solve it?But I can't successfull

Comment: This is an application of the [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product); see also sciona’s answer.

Comment: Oh,It's Nice! Thank you +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** What is the  coefficient of $x^n$ in $\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} a_kx^k\right)^2$ ?